# Finding chiral-symmetric degenerate states numerically

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry, anticommutator

I am dealing with a Chiral-symmetric Hamiltonian such that

$$
^{−1}=−.
$$

Two of its eigenstates have zero eigenvalue and fulfill $∣_{\alpha}⟩=^{_{\alpha}}∣_{\alpha}⟩$, while the rest have finite eigenvalues and are pairwise symmetric. When I diagonalize my Hamiltonian numerically however, the zero energy states get mixed and the resulting eigenstates are therefore not symmetric.

When I have a symmetry that commutes with my Hamiltonian, $[,]=0$, and two degenerate eigenstates, to obtain the symmetric ones I can just add a small perturbation to the Hamiltonian proportional to $$ which breaks the degeneracy and does not modify the eigenstates. Is there a similar trick one can do to obtain symmetric degenerate eigenstates for symmetries that anticommute with the Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not apply $S$ to your numerical eigenstates?  If so  $(1+S)/2 $ and $(1-S)/2$ project out the $S\to \pm 1$ eigenstates.